# What is a 'Target Server' in a SQL Server Agent Job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Can someone explain what a 'Target Server' is in this instance.  Also, what it means to "Target Multiple Servers"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Target server allows the job to be run against a different server than the one it is defined on.

Multiple Target Servers allows you to define a job once (say a routine backup job) and have it execute against many servers (thus backing each of them up).

UPDATE:

MSDN Documentation here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180992.aspx

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as going into the 'Steps' section of your job and defining what 'Database' your TSQL is going to run on?

Comment: No it's managed at a more enterprise level than that. This integrates with SQL's policy based server management. Read the documentation at the link to get a clearer picture.

Answer (score 1):

A target server is a specific location where data is stored, such as database, or a collection of databases.

A target can also be an application that provides data to be backed up.

Multiple Target Servers permit  you to define a job who execute on many servers